# How to make full height sidebar with dynamic main content?

Tags: css, angular, semantic-ui

I have an angular2 app with left a sidebar and dynamic main content.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="full_height">
  <div class="sidebar">Some content</div>
  <div class="main">Some dynamic content</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  width:          100%;
  height:         100%;
  margin:         0;
}
.full_height{
    display:        flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items:    stretch;
}
.sidebar{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.main{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

I need the sidebar grow to 100% height of the browser body if no information in the main block. And I need the sidebar and the main block have equal height when a big amount of information have been loaded to the main block via AJAX.

How to make the first part work?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w9j6oa8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make full `height` sidebar then sidebar will be `fixed position` and rest of the content will be `relative position`. Please check the below **Snippet**.

```css
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.full_height{
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .full_height{
    padding-left: 330px;
  }
}
.sidebar{
  background-color: #5c5c5c;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .sidebar{
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 310px;
    z-index: 1030;
  }
}
.main{
  background-color: #009688;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full_height">
  <div class="sidebar">Some content</div>
  <div class="main">Some dynamic content</div>
</div>
```

**Snippet two** This relative content

```css
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.full_height{
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .full_height{
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.sidebar{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #009688;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .sidebar{
    flex-basis: 310px;
    max-width: 310px;
  }
}
.main{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .main{
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="full_height">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar content</div>
  <div class="main">Main Content</div>
</div>
```

> Check the **Snippet** in full width view. All snippet is responsive.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just forgot to assign a 100% height to the HTML element. Is this what you tried to do ?

```css
html, body{
  width:          100%;
  height:         100%;
  margin:         0;
}
.full_height{
  display:        flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items:    stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.main{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="full_height">
  <div class="sidebar">Some content</div>
  <div class="main">Some dynamic content</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is not work when content in the main block loads via AJAX and the main block height becomes larger than the screen.

Comment: So far this is the best method. It works like a charm with *Bootstrap 5*

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the `.sidebar` and `.main` to fill the entire screen, just add the 100vh height.

```
.sidebar,
.main {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: `vh` meaning Viewport Height (in %).